# java API with mongoDB replica sets 'MongoClient ' is deprecated

Tags: mongodb

I am using  java API  to  connected  to  mongodb  with  replica sets like

```
ServerAddress serverAddress1 = new ServerAddress("10.28.136.83",37000);
ServerAddress serverAddress2 = new ServerAddress("10.28.136.84",37000);
ServerAddress serverAddress3 = new ServerAddress("10.28.136.85",37000);

                addressLists.add(serverAddress1);
                addressLists.add(serverAddress2);
                addressLists.add(serverAddress3);
                credentials = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("root", "admin", "root".toCharArray());
                credentialsLists.add(credentials);
                mongoClient = new MongoClient(addressLists, credentialsLists);
```

it works  but `MongoClient`  shows it's  deprecated .

```
 /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public MongoClient(ServerAddress addr, List<MongoCredential> credentialsList) {
        this(addr, credentialsList, MongoClientOptions.builder().build());
    }
```

I wanted to asked  what is the newest way to connected to  mongodb  replica sets  .  or any better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the answer of @dnickless, but to pinpoint: In your case, you pass to mongo's ctor **a list of** ServerAddress (because this is a replica set), and **a list of** MongoCredential. So according to [the docs (version 3.7)](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html), you should use a ctor that accepts the same list of servers, but only a single MongoCredential, (plus add MongoOptions...)

this is what you use:

```
@Deprecated
public MongoClient​(List<ServerAddress> seeds,
                   List<MongoCredential> credentialsList)
Deprecated. Prefer MongoClient(List, MongoCredential, MongoClientOptions)
```

so this is the one you need:

```
public MongoClient​(List<ServerAddress> seeds,
                   MongoCredential credential,
                   MongoClientOptions options)
```

where credential - the credential used to authenticate **all** connections

Comment: I deleted my answer. I was mislead by not reading through the example code properly and only focusing on the (incorrect) deprecated constructor given above.

Comment: @thanks  a lot  ,could I use ' MongoClientURI'  to  replica set  ?  is it better?

Comment: yes you can. read the docs (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html#getHosts--) and make sure to mark replicaSet=name (and set the name of the RS)

Comment: @OhadR  ,hi I am sorry  to trouble you again  ,when started  the log show   'Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:37000, localhost:37001, localhost:37002], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, .....'     it  can't get the replicaSetName?   even  I  use 'MongoClientOptions.getRequiredReplicaSetName()'  it return null  .

Comment: did u set a replicaSet name? (see my previous comment from yesterday)